# Dictionary values are in "set", how can I manage to remove the sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

```
dict = {'a': {'Islamabad'}, 'b' : {'Islamabad'}, 'c': {'Paris'},
       'd': {'Bern'}, 'e': {'Moscow'}}
```

result wanted:

```
dict = {'a': 'Islamabad', 'b' : 'Islamabad', 'c': 'Paris',
       'd': 'Bern', 'e': 'Moscow'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get one element from a set is `set.pop()`.

```
dct = {'a': {'Islamabad'}, 'b' : {'Islamabad'}, 'c': {'Paris'},
       'd': {'Bern'}, 'e': {'Moscow'}}

dct = {k: v.pop() for k, v in dct.items()}
print(dct)
```

`v.pop()` modifies the original set `v`. If this is not desired, use `next(iter(v))`.

Update: Or use an [assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) with a *[target_list]* or *(target_list)* (--> comment from @Kelly Bundy)

P.S. don't use `dict` as a variable name

Comment: Or `{k: v for k, [v] in dct.items()}` (pity we can't assign to `{v}`, that would be nice).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert set to string using * with str() function ( str(*set) ). This way it will remove brackets from the string

You have to loop over the dict and change each value to string like this

```
dict1 = {'a': {'Islamabad'}, 'b' : {'Islamabad'}, 'c': {'Paris'}, 'd': {'Bern'}, 'e': {'Moscow'}}

dict1 = {k: str(*v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

output: `{'a': 'Islamabad', 'b': 'Islamabad', 'c': 'Paris', 'd': 'Bern', 'e': 'Moscow'}`

and also, don't use "dict" to name your dictionaries. "dict" is python built-in word which may lead to error in some scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Extremely poor code, please don't use this in any other cases than your own, but this works with your current example.

```py
import ast

dictt = {'a': {'Islamabad'}, 'b' : {'Islamabad'}, 'c': {'Paris'},
       'd': {'Bern'}, 'e': {'Moscow'}}

dictt = str(dictt).replace("{","") #Convert to string and remove {
dictt = "{" + dictt.replace("}","") +"}" #remove } and re-add outer { }
dictt = ast.literal_eval(dictt) #Back to dict

print(dictt)
```

output:
 `{'a': 'Islamabad', 'b': 'Islamabad', 'c': 'Paris', 'd': 'Bern', 'e': 'Moscow'}`